# Como separar cada elemento de uma lista, com uma String, em uma linha

Tags: python-3.x, programação-funcional, clojure

O problema é simples, gostaria de adicionar um elemento, a uma lista gerada em tempo real, para cada iteração dada. Por exemplo, se a lista l for gerada através de `[x for x in range(10) if x%2==0]`, então quero que o caractere 'a' apareça entre cada elemento da lista. Ou seja, a lista l seria [0,'a',2,'a', 4, 'a',6,'a',8]. Para resolver este problema há duas restrições: utilizar somente a biblioteca padrão e utilizar list comprehension.

O que eu tentei até agora:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505529/appending-item-to-lists-within-a-list-comprehension

Contudo, essa solução resolve o problema utilizando sublistas.

Propósito:

Minha linguagem de trabalho atualmente é Python, mas tenho investido algum tempo aprendendo Clojure. Nessa linguagem, puramente funcional, essa tarefa seria resolvida da seguinte forma:

```
(->> (range 10)(filter even?)(interpose "a") )
```

Gostaria de saber como resolver esse mesmo problema de forma elegante e pythonica :)

Comment: Mas tem que ser tudo numa chamada ? Não pode usar funções nativas ? Quais são as restrições mais especificamente falando ? `zip` resolve o problema com elegância, intercalando/mesclando dois iteráveis em que um pode ser uma lista de vários `a`

Comment: Bem lembrado! Não precisa ser uma única chamada, mas precisa caber em uma única linha. Quero dizer, precisa ser o mais sucinto possível

Comment: O problema, Isac, é que não se trata de um segundo iterável, mas sim de um "separator"

Comment: Mas a lista e o separador tem de ser gerados na mesma linha ? E a lista tem de ser gerada com list comprehension como indicou ?

Comment: Sim, Isac. O separador é uma variável a ser recebida. Talvez o uso de uma função lambda seja um caminho possível

Comment: Eu tou com uma certa relutancia em responder porque suspeito que não é aquilo que está a procura devido a outros motivos que não explicou. Mas assumindo que tem a lista `l`. Consegue o resultado que pretende utilizando `list(zip(l, separador*len(l)))`, sendo o `separador` algo como `a`.

Comment: Desta forma, o resultado é uma lista de tuplas. Sei como diminuir as dimensões em apenas uma lista, mas me pergunto se esta é a forma mais simples de resolver o problema. De qualquer forma, resolve. Obrigado!

Comment: Se quiser em lista normal pode utilizar itertools com `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(l, separador*len(l))))` e assumindo que importa previamente o itertools com `import itertools`. Dá sempre para fazer só é preciso saber o que você quer exatamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta alterar a posição da condicional e utilizar o que, em Python, é basicamente um operador ternário:

```
lista = [x if x % 2 == 0 else 'a' for x in range(10)]
```

O valor de `x` será de [0, 10[, incluindo-o na lista se for par, caso contrário é inserido o caractere `'a'`. O resultado será:

```
[0, 'a', 2, 'a', 4, 'a', 6, 'a', 8, 'a']
```